# How to call rest API using python selenium?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, python

I have a scenario where I need to call a rest API in my python selenium script but I am not sure how to do it.

If anyone as idea on it can you please help me out .

The API used is to delete the phone number.

Answer (score 3):

[Request](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) is the Python built-in HTTP library.

```
r = requests.get('https://api.github.com/user', auth=('user', 'pass'))
print( r.status_code ) # Print 200
```

If you want to systematic valid Rest Endpoints, you may want to look at [pyresttest](https://github.com/svanoort/pyresttest) or [Tavern](https://taverntesting.github.io/).

Answer (score 0):

Selenium just controls the browser, it is not intended to make rest calls. Selenium only lets you to `GET` particular URL (as you do when you request a regular html page from a server) using `driver.get(..)`.

However I believe this is not your case because implementing data editing using GET requests is a sort of bad practice since it exposes high security risks.

So you should use dedicated libs like João advices.